# CGPoint wrong assignment

Tags: ios, cgpoint

My code:

```
CGFloat scaleFactor = newSize.width / oldSize.width;
CGFloat newCenterX = center_.x * scaleFactor;
CGFloat newCenterY = center_.y * scaleFactor;

CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(newCenterX, newCenterY);
//newCenter.x = newCenterX;
//newCenter.y = newCenterY;

CGFloat newRaduis = raduis_ * scaleFactor;
newCenter.y += newSize.height - ceilf(scaleFactor) * oldSize.height;
NSLog(@"Convertion from %@ to %@", NSStringFromCGSize(oldSize), NSStringFromCGSize(newSize));
NSLog(@"old center = %@, old radius = %f", NSStringFromCGPoint(center_), raduis_);
NSLog(@"new center = %@, new radius = %f", NSStringFromCGPoint(newCenter), newRaduis);
NSLog(@"new center x = %f, new center y = %f", newCenterX, newCenterY);
```

And output:

```
2012-09-14 14:18:35.027 TestApp[425:4b93] Convertion from {1080, 1920} to {320, 415}
2012-09-14 14:18:35.031 TestApp[425:4b93] old center = {246, 822}, old radius = 20.000000
2012-09-14 14:18:35.033 TestApp[425:4b93] new center = {73, -1261}, new radius = 5.925926
2012-09-14 14:18:35.035 TestApp[425:4b93] new center x = 73, new center y = 244
```

In output - new center = {73, -1261}, new radius = 5.925926. Why center y value is negative? What I do wrong?

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Even if I write - CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(newCenterX, 100.0) - in output newCenter.y still be negative!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because of your line

```
newCenter.y += newSize.height - ceilf(scaleFactor) * oldSize.height;
```

- `scaleFactor` is about `0.2962` so `ceilf(scaleFactor)` is equal to `1`.
- `newSize.height` is `415`, `oldSize.height` is `1920`, so `415 - 1*1920` is `-1505`, and `newCenter.y += -1505` makes `newCenter.y` change from `243.556` to `243.556 + (-1505)` = `1261.444`.

So this seems legit that newCenter.y is `-1261` after this line.